# Как сделать действие перед выходом из приложения на PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

Как сделать какое-то действие перед закрытием приложения на "крестик", например удалить файл?

Приложение написано по этому шаблону:

```
import sys
from gui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    def MyFunction(self):
        pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переопределите colseEvent:

```
import sys
from gui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    def MyFunction(self):
        print("Привет pushButton")
        #pass

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Переопределить colseEvent
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question\
        (self, 'Информация',
            "Вы уверены, что хотите уйти?",
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            print("Пока pushButton")
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]